# Is it allowed to swap rows/col in 0 = det(A-λI) so I put my 4x4 A matrix in a lower triangular form?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, diagonalization

So, I want to diagonalize this 4x4 Matrix 
A = \begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0\\-1&3&1&0\\2&-2&0&0\\2&-1&3&-5\end{bmatrix}

and putting it in a lower triangular form gonna make the whole process straightforward. So, my question is is my very first step in finding the eigenvalues as solutions of 0 = det(A-λI) expressed 0 = det of \begin{bmatrix}2-λ&0&0&0\\-1&3-λ&1&0\\2&-2&0-λ&0\\2&-1&3&-5-λ\end{bmatrix}
equivalent to 0 = (-1)^(2-1) det of
\begin{bmatrix}2-λ&0&0&0\\2&-2-λ&0&0\\-1&3&1-λ&0\\2&-1&3&-5-λ\end{bmatrix} ----(1)

justified by det(A) = (-1)^(i-1)* det(B), where i the row swapped by i-1 and B in this case is: 
\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0\\2&-2&0&0\\-1&3&1&0\\2&-1&3&-5\end{bmatrix}

I am not sure if (1) legit or not but it gives me correct eigenvalues (the diagonal elements) or it is just a coincidence.

Thank you!

Comment: If you consider the diagnoal elements as follows:
2−λ, −2−λ 1−λ,−5−λ whose product is the determinant, then their zeros are the eigenvalues that is what I meant above there.

Comment: You can swap columns *after* subtracting $\lambda I$, not before. Try doing it with a simpler example such as $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\\3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$p_A(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I) =  (1-\lambda)(4-\lambda) - 6$$
Let $$B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1\\4 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$p_B(\lambda) = \det(B - \lambda I) =  (2-\lambda)(3-\lambda) - 4 = PA$$
where $P$ is a permutation matrix. Arranging $p_A(\lambda)$ and $p_B(\lambda)$, you will find that $$p_A(\lambda)\neq p_B(\lambda)$$

> **In general,**
>   if $P$ is a permutation matrix then
>   $$\det (A - \lambda I) = \det(PP(A-\lambda I)) = \det(P(A-\lambda I)P) = \det(PAP - \lambda I) \neq \det(PA  - \lambda I)$$

Comment: So, it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: But, what about an upper/lower triangular matrix, would it work then?

Comment: I mean take A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} has same eigenvalues as permuted A (with row/col swap)